# Возможность вариативности постановки запятых в конкретном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация

На своём ли месте стоят выделенные знаки препинания?

*И даже, казалось бы, самые незначительные вещи в этот момент приобретают свой(,) абсолютно исключительный(,) смысл.*

Существует ли возможность авторской расстановки запятых, обозначенных в скобках: например, можно ли вообще обойтись без них или, допустим, поставить только первую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь сложно. Теоретически возможны все три варианта, но нельзя поступать как вздумается.

Если ставим две запятые, то это уточнение:
*И даже, казалось бы, самые незначительные вещи в этот момент приобретают свой [собственный], [а именно] абсолютно исключительный, смысл.* || *Абсолютно исключительный* — новая информация. Логическое ударение на слове "свой". Но этот вариант не подходит по смыслу.
Почему там значение "собственный"? Потому что "*особый, а именно абсолютно исключительный*" не подходит для уточнения и не звучит.

Без запятых и уточнения воспринимается значение "собственный":
*И даже, казалось бы, самые незначительные вещи в этот момент приобретают свой [собственный] абсолютно исключительный смысл.* || Оно здесь не подходит. И речевая избыточность: и так понятно, что он собственный, а не чужой.
Если "особый", то получается ерунда: *особый абсолютно исключительный смысл*. Речевая избыточность, потому что "особый" и есть "исключительный".

Одна запятая может стоять при таком смысле:
*И даже, казалось бы, самые незначительные вещи в этот момент приобретают свой и абсолютно исключительный смысл.* || Без И (с запятой) оно звучит не по-русски.

Но у Розенталя есть следующее:
Иные отношения мы усматриваем при пояснительных определениях, которые являются **другим названием** по отношению к предшествующему определению, а не его
уточнением. Например: *Новое, радостное чувство овладело мной.*
"Свой" (= "особый") и "абсолютно исключительный" похожи, второе поясняет значение первого. Получается, что можно так:
*И даже, казалось бы, самые незначительные вещи в этот момент приобретают свОй [особый], абсолютно исключительный смысл.* || И это лучший вариант.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне также этот вариант видится наиболее правильным. Ну а если слово «свой» имеет здесь значение «особый», а «абсолютно исключительный» — это уточнение [особый, (а именно какой?) абсолютно исключительный], то можно ли вот в таком случае поставить две запятые, как считаете?

Comment: Да, но можно сказать, что "особый" и есть "исключительный", а "абсолютно" — для пафоса, чтоб звучало интригующе. Ещё планирую в этом всём разбираться (не сейчас, а на неделе-другой), сообщу (придёт оповещение), если ответ обновится.

Comment: Буду благодарен! Вопросы такого характера возникают у меня нередко, но только сейчас я, наконец, решился публично написать о «наболевшем», так сказать.

Comment: Честно говоря, это одна из самых сложных тем. Чуть ли не единственная, в которой пока не разобрался полностью. Честно говоря, интересно, какие ещё вопросы такого характера у вас возникали. Думаю, что они попроще.

Comment: Вы конкретно про эту тему или про трудности с постановкой запятых в принципе?

Comment: Про всё. Самое трудное — это не пунктуация, а стилистика. Даже и не сравнить.

Comment: Пожалуй, меня всё больше интересует набирающее в последнее время популярность словечко «типа» (по значению схожа со словами «вроде», «будто»). См. примеры: [Он типа уехал; Несколько дней назад мы типа начали встречаться; Она сказала типа приходи завтра]. Как думаете, насколько данная словоформа стилистически приемлема и вообще имеет ли она право на жизнь? Что делать с запятыми, нужны ли они при этом слове? Я как погляжу — где-то его выделяют, где-то нет, и неспроста, наверное.

Comment: Оно может означать "похоже на то" (сам так порой употребляю), а может употребляться без надобности. Во втором случае его используют в первую очередь гопники (персонажи/люди) наряду с "йоу", "чувиха" и т.п. Про обособление здесь: https://i.imgur.com/GEMU3Xc.png Интересный пример "*Она сказала типа приходи завтра*". Если строго, то это прямая речь. Или надо так: *Она сказала, чтобы ты типа пришёл завтра* (здесь похоже на употребление без причины). Слово приемлемо, но его не стоит пихать куда попало (второй случай).

Answer (score 0):

Запятые не ставятся, так как есть правило ([4-й пункт](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108)), что определительный оборот, стоящий после притяжательного местоимения, не отделяется от него запятой. Для второй запятой нет причин. Пример из Розенталя:

> Ваш проверенный на практике метод заслуживает внимания.

Примеры из Нац. корпуса:

> А сатана уже сидит на некрашеной табуретке, самодовольно вздернув свой абсолютно неправдоподобный нос. [Анатолий Мариенгоф. Мой век, мои друзья и подруги (1956-1960)]

> Мать потом сказала, что в этом подборе все имело свой понятный им смысл. [М. Л. Гаспаров. Записи и выписки (2001)]

> Она имела свой и даже значительный смысл. [И. Ф. Анненский. Вторая книга отражений (1909)]

> Ибо термин “протестантизм” есть термин технический и обретший свой вполне конкретный смысл задолго до моего рождения. [Андрей Кураев. Протестантам о православии (1997)
> .

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131800/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett----).